# Can one prove $(g_1H)(g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$, $g_1, g_2 \in G$ if and only if $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$.

I have proven in an exercise that $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$ implies $(g_1H)(g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$, $g_1, g_2 \in G$
where $(g_1H)(g_2H) = (xy | x\in g_1H, y\in g_2H)$.

Can one prove $(g_1H)(g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$, $g_1, g_2 \in G$ if and only if $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$ ?

I have been sitting trying to come up with a counter example. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

/Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Put $g_2=g_1^{-1}$, then  $g_1Hg_1^{-1}H=H$, hence  $g_1Hg_1^{-1}\subseteq H$.

**Addendum:** More details:

1) Putting $g_1=g_2=1$ we get $H$ is a subgroup (so the condition "$H$ is a subgroup" is unnecessary).

2) Put $g_2=g_1^{−1}$, then $g_1Hg_1^{−1}H=H$. Hence  $g_1Hg_1^{−1}\subseteq H$, i.e. $g_1H\subseteq Hg_1$. From here Hg_1^{−1}\subseteq g_1^{−1}H. This is true for all $g_1$, so $xH\subseteq Hx$ and $Hx\subseteq xH$ for all $x$.

Comment: Sorry, are you proving $(g_1H)(g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$, $g_1, g_2 \in G$ implies $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$ ? - or is this some counter example ?

Comment: It follows from $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ that $gH\subseteq Hg$ and  $Hg^{-1}\subseteq g^{-1}H$ for ALL $g\in G$. So $xH=Hx$ for all $x\in G$.

Comment: But as this proof shows, $gHg^{-1} \leq G$ is just a subgroup in $G$ not neccesarily a subset of $H$ for arbitary $g \in G$ ?
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_of_Subgroup_is_Subgroup

Comment: But your condition implies that $H$ is a subgroup: take $g_1=g_2=1$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've edited.
What i'm interested in is:
$(g_1H)(g_2H)=(g_1g_2H)$ implies $\forall  g \in G (gH = Hg)$,  then I have proven both ways in the bicondition.

Also, thanks for your help so far Boris.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Boris Can you prove the implication ?

Comment: Let $(g_1H)(g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$ for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$. 1) Putting $g_1=g_2=1$ we get $H$ is a subgroup.   2) Put $g_2=g_1^{-1}$, then  $g_1Hg_1^{-1}H =H$. Hence  $g_1Hg_1^{-1}\subseteq H$, i.e. $g_1H\subseteq Hg_1$. From here  $Hg_1^{-1}\subseteq g_1^{-1}H$. This is true for all $g_1$, so $xH\subseteq Hx$ and $Hx\subseteq xH$ for all $x$.

Comment: Good luck, Nicolas!

Comment: Maybe we should put your answer as an 'answer', since the answer is a comment.

Comment: You conclude $g_1H(g_1)^{-1} \subseteq H$ since $(g_1H(g_1)^{-1})H$ not equal $H$ if $g_1H(g_1)^{-1}$ is not a subset of $H$ ?

Comment: OK, I added the answer. But I didn't undwerstand your last question in the comment.

Comment: You write: $g_1Hg_1^{−1}H=H$. Hence  $g_1Hg_1^{−1}\subseteq H$. How does you prove this? $(g_1H)(g_1^{-1}H) = \{g_1xg_1^{-1}y | x, y \in H\} = \{(g_1xg_1^{-1})y | x, y \in H\}  = (g_1Hg_1^{-1})H = \{zy | z \in (g_1Hg_1^{-1}), y \in H\}$. Then $(g_1Hg_1^{-1}) \subseteq H$, since $1 \in H$ ?

Comment: I proved as follows: $g_1Hg_1^{−1}=g_1Hg_1^{−1}\cdot 1 \subseteq g_1Hg_1^{−1}H=H$.